# ¿Como inserto una fuente en Css?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estaba viendo un curso de html y he seguido al pie de la letra lo que decía el profesor pero no consigo utilizar una fuente externa. Según el vídeo se debe hacer así:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MiFuente';
  src: url("fuentes/Back to Black Demo.ttf");
}
#titulo {
  font-family: 46px 'MiFuente';
}
```

Y he echo eso y no consigo el resultado deseado. No sé si esta bien lo que hago o no por que llevo intentando un buen rato y las letras que quiero que se muestren siguen sin cambio alguno.

Comment: Estas las fonts en la carpeta `fuentes`? Tambien intenta con `fuentes/Back to Black Demo.ttf` y dinos que pasa.

Comment: Prueba a quitar 46px

Comment: oie una pregunta si la fuente la tengo en una carpeta "CursoHtml" y luego las fuentes la tengo en Una carpeta "fuentes" en el atributo src() debo especificar CursoHtml/fuentes/<nombre de la fuente> o no por que justo cuando lei tu comentario se me ocurrio que quizas puede ser eso tu crees?

Comment: Depende, en css las url son relativas al documento desde donde las llamas.

Comment: @Aitor gracias me funciono cuando quite el 46 px, bueno en el videotutorial el no lo quita y funciona pero que raro quizas es por que sus videos son del 2014 y ya a cambiado algo hasta este entonce

Comment: @VladimirJoel ¿seguro que es `font-family` y no solo `font`? Si es `font-family` quizás podría funcionar si hubiera una coma (`,`) entre el 46px y el nombre de la fuente.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro  no lo se pero justo ahora acabo de hacer lo que dices   font-face {
      font-family: 200px, 'MiFuente';
      src: url('fuentes/Back to Black Demo.ttf');
    }

Comment: los comentarios no permiten usar dos arrobas pero en mi codigo si lo puse lo digo por si las dudas ya que mi comentario anterior tiene el font-face sin arroba

Comment: bien @AlvaroMontoro no sale incluso le puse 200px , 'MiFuente'; y no es más se quita el efecto que ya habia conseguido.

Comment: Me refería para `#titulo` no para el `@font-face`, pero está bien. @Aitor o tú deberías poner la solución como respuesta y aceptarla cuando pase el tiempo requerido.

Answer (score 3):

En la propiedad `font-family` no puedes añadir el tamaño de la fuente, tienes que utilizar `font` o `font size`,

Ejemplo con `font`:

```
#titulo {
  font: 46px 'MiFuente';
}
```

Ejemplo con `font-size`:

```
#titulo {
  font-family:'MiFuente';
  font-size : 46px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Te pongo un ***ejemplo de importación y uso de una fuente externa***, dentro de los estilos CSS (documento externo)

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Glegoo);

html {
    /* para la selección de fuente pongo dos opciones separadas por coma, si la primera no carga, usa la segunda.*/
    font: normal 16px 'Glegoo', serif; 
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: blue;
}
```

***Otro ejemplo***, cargándolos dentro de la declaración de estilos de la propia página y almacenándolos con la aplicación, además cambio la familia de la fuente, declarando una propia:

```
<title> ... </title>
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'cl-xxx';
        src: url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.eot');
        src: url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.eot')  format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.woff') format('woff'),
        url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.ttf')  format('truetype'),
        url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.svg')  format('svg');
    }
</style>
```

Observa que he usado una URL absoluta, creo recordar que tenía problemas con los iconos-fuente con las relativas. También hay varios tipos para la fuente, ocurre que cada navegador lee un tipo, bien sea woff, ttf... lo que obliga a ponerlas todas, de otro modo, aunque la cargues de forma correcta puede ser que el navegador/es que uses no la carguen.

Answer (score 1):

En el estilo que le estás poniendo al elemento **#Titulo** estás usando la propiedad **font-family** la cual acepta sólo el parámetro **nombre de familia o genérico**, pero tú le agregaste el tamaño de fuenta. Creo que confundiste la propiedad *font*, que sí acepta los parámetros como los usaste.

Te dejo aquí la documentación de esta propiedad.

[CSS font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/font-family)

Comment: hola que tal siéndote sincero no se mucho de html ni de css pero he echo de estas dos formas las cuales de igual manera obtengo el resultado pero la pregunta ahora seria cual es la manera mas recomendada de hacerlo                                                                  
      @font-face {
      font-family:'MiFuente';
      src: url('fuentes/Back to Black Demo.ttf');
    }

    #titulo {
      font-family: 'MiFuente';
      font-size: 46px;
    }

Comment: SIGUIENDO TU RECOMENDACION :                                             
    @font-face {
      font-family:'MiFuente';
      src: url('fuentes/Back to Black Demo.ttf');
    }

    #titulo {
      font: 46px 'MiFuente'
    }

Comment: Cualquiera de las dos formas es correcta, sólo que *font-family* es sólo para especificar la familia de la fuente (en tu caso 'MiFuente'), luego tendrías qué especificar el tamaño, el estilo, etc. 
*font* es una forma abreviada de hacer todas esas especificaciones en una sola propiedad.

[Propiedades Font](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Debes definir bien la ruta de tu fuente, y la fuente debe tener el formato correcto (.ttf).

> @font-face{
>       font-family: "opensans";
>       src: url(../../fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf) format("truetype"); }
>
> body {
>       font-family: "opensans" !important; }

Espero te seriva